# How to modify jscript to prevent one specific link from scrolling?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this code for scrolling inside the page. Basically checks for internal links, if they are interval, adds a smooth scrolling:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

However, I also have a slideshow in the same page. This uses [Carousel from Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/). This code clashes with the slideshow and I would like to disable smooth scrolling for this `href`.

How can I add a code to prevent this clash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your selector to explicitly exclude any anchor elements inside your slideshow. Assuming the slideshow is in an element with the id `#slideshow` (as an example):

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#], #slideshow a)').click(function() {
```

Though personally I find it more readable to use the `.not()` method rather than the `:not()` selector (because syntax colour highlighting works on methods but not inside a single string):

```
$('a[href*=#]').not("[href=#], #slideshow a").click(function() {
```