# Remove some links in a smooth scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have found an elegant bit of jquery for smooth scrolling and placed it at the bottom of the index page. However, in media < 600px wide, where I use a menu-link to toggle open the nav, the page scrolls up on each click. Is there a way to filter out this link, or whatever is causing the scroll to occur? This issue can be viewed on reduced-width screens at http://lma.la

The script:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').not('a.menu-link').animate({ //THIS DOES NOT WORK
                 scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1500);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks anyway, folks; I found the answer in another post. I had tried the .not in the wrong place and in the right place with the wrong syntax. Now it works. The post answer is at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884059/how-to-modify-jscript-to-prevent-one-specific-link-from-scrolling?rq=1

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the # in the < 600px menu link; which is causing it to go to the top of the page.

replace that # with javascript:; and it should fix your issue.

Glad you found your own answer well done :)